# Possible to reload the page when a cross domain child popup window is closed? IE7+

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, internet-explorer-7, cross-domain

Is it possible to reload the parent page when a child popup window is closed? the child popup is in a **different domain** unfortunately. If so, how? I am working with IE7+, but the site is in compatibility mode. I.e., I am trying to do something like:

```
//in parent window
var popup = window.open('http://otherdomain.com/popup', '', 'status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,directories=no,location=no,top=0,left=0,resizable=yes');

popup.onunload = function(){
    window.location = window.location;
};
```

I've had some code work while within the same domain, but when cross domain, that produced:

```
0x800a0046 - JavaScript runtime error: Permission denied
```

I know that popups are a bad practice, but that's what I have to do in this case.

It seems like postmessage doesn't work in IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add code to the popup, add this in the parent window

```
window.name="mainwindow";
```

---

and add this in the popup

```
window.onbeforeunload=function() {
  window.open("http://openersite.com/whatever","mainwindow");
}
```

Comment: If the parent window is closed, then the child window is closed, it will open the parent window again, unfortunately

Comment: Yes, that is true. You can add a frame to the pop up so the parent can close it too